# Can I make a public S3 Bucket accessible to whitelisted IPs or DNS names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, drupal

We are facing an issue with S3 private files which is taking excess time to load on a Drupal website.
Can we make a S3 bucket public but restrict the public files to whitelisted IP addresses or DNS names.

A link to the documentation would be a great help

Comment: A "public bucket" is, by definition, accessible to anyone on the Internet. I presume your goal is to keep it as a _private bucket_ but grant access to a range of IP addresses. Can you tell us more about your current architecture and what is leading it to "take excess time to load"?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict an Amazon S3 bucket so that it is accessible only to a range of IP addresses. This can be done by **adding a Bucket Policy**.

See: [Bucket policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html)

For example:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BCKET-NAME/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This permits access to an object (`GetObject`), but only if the request is coming from the CIDR range given in `aws:SourceIp`. This can a *list* of CIDR ranges too.

It is not possible to "restrict by DNS names", but a bucket can be restricted by `referer` (which is the domain of the website that the user was using when they clicked a link in their browser). However, this is not a secure method and can be easily faked.

Comment: You should also look at pre-signed URLs and CloudFront